# Eloquent is slow?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I just uploaded my project to my hosting provider and the database queries executed via Eloquent are very, very slow.

For example, this controller return a list of businesses:

```
$business = Business::all();
return Response::json($business);
```

This query takes about 2-5 seconds but via localhost it only takes 0.112ms (approximately).

I did some tests with the native MySQl driver packaged with PHP and the queries execute very fast.

So, what is wrong? Does my hosting provider not support Laravel?

Comment: Is `2-5 seconds` including request cycle or just `query elapsed time` ?

Comment: Is your database on the same server as your php? Give us more info about your hosting setup and your models.

Comment: If the exact same code is fast on your localhost but slow on your production host, then the changing factor is probably 1) the amount of data and 2) the hosting, including available server resources. What didn't change was the code and it's inherent speed.

Comment: Since your question is actually a statement that ends in a question-mark, are we allowed to answer with questions ending in exclamation-points!!!

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? query elapsed time is not for sure.